# how to copy from a field from a website using vbs

Tags: vbscript

Hi i am new to vbs and I am trying to create a vbs script to enter data into a field on a website and output the text returned to a text file
thats what I created so far:

```html
Dim objIE


    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Visible = 1 


objIE.navigate "http://translation.babylon.com/english/to-spanish/"
    
WScript.Sleep 100
Do while objIE.busy
Wscript.sleep 200
Loop

objIE.Document.all.Item("translator_input").Value = "sample text"
 
WScript.Sleep 100
Do while objIE.busy
Wscript.sleep 200
Loop

Call objIE.Document.all.Item("btnTranslate").Click

Objie.Quit
```

any ideas how to copy the transelation into a txt. or excel doc.?

Answer (score -1):

Using Chrome's DOM inspector, it appears the translated text is put into this element:

```
<div id="resltext" name="resultext">
</div>
```

So you should be able to get the text by just looking for the ID and returning the value of `innerText`:

```
strTranslated = objIE.Document.All.Item("resltext").innerText
```

Comment: thanks, but could you be more specific as of what to write? that it should be pasted into an exsisting doc.?

Comment: `objIE.Document.All.Item("resltext").innerText` should contain the translated text.